# Sitecore Headless Service Install on AKS

Tags: jss, aks

I want to deploy `Sitecore Headless Service` on `AKS` But unable to find any reference code for official and unofficial code.

But I got this link for Docker for references - https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/tree/master/examples/helix-basic-nextjs

Can you please provide me any reference to deploy on AKS for SAME.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The method of installing Sitecore Headless Services depends on your deployment architecture.

You can install Sitecore Headless Services:

1. [Using the package .zip.](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/install-headless-services-using-the-package--zip-file.html)
2. [As an Azure Web Deploy Package (WDP).](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/install-headless-services-as-a-web-deploy-package-on-azure.html)
3. [In Sitecore Containers.](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/install-headless-services-in-containers.html)

As in your case, when working with Sitecore Containers, you can install the Headless Services module in your Sitecore container with the help of Dockerfiles refer this ([Link](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/211/sitecore-headless-development/install-headless-services-in-containers.html)).

You need to add Sitecore modules `(JavaScript Services (JSS) / Sitecore Headless Services)` that are available as Docker asset images and the Sitecore runtime Dockerfile instructions that you must include for each role when you build custom images. Refer [Sitecore module reference](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/developer-tools/sitecore-module-reference.html)

With the release of Sitecore 10, Sitecore now support running the application inside of Containers and deploying to Kubernetes (K8s). Refer to this video by Rob to learn more about [Running Sitecore on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2o_ujoH6LQ)

Hope it helps!